# How can I get opener's element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just like in [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript):

```
opener.document.getElementByName
```

jQuery:
??

Is there any way to get `opener`'s element  with [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery)?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then you simply pass the opener as the second parameter in the jQuery function, like so:

```
var abc = $("[name=abc]", window.opener.document);
```

You may also reference the jQuery object directly from the opener, like so:

```
var abc = window.opener.jQuery("[name=abc]");
```

Answer (score 7):

```
window.opener.$("[name=elementName]")
```

Replace `elementName` with the name of your element.